# Performing PostgreSQL match using OR on a JSON field

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model that looks like this

```
class Message(db.Model):

    content = db.Column(JSON)
```

I want to perform a search on that field which contain some JSON fields

normally when I something like this it works

```
Message.query.filter(Message.content['summary'].cast(Unicode).match(search_term))
```

Now I want to use or another field if the field summary doesn't exist or is empty

using either with or without casting fails with programming error of types needs to be boolean

```
Message.query.filter(Message.content['summary'] | Message.content['text+video'].match(search_term))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *Elmer* on the #sqlalchemy IRC channel, the logic was not correct, that's how I should have performed the search

```
Message.query.filter(Message.content['summary'].cast(Unicode).match(search_term) | Message.content['text'].cast(Unicode).match(search_term))
```

People who are interested should also follow this link where there is a related question with a better answer [SQLAlchemy Text Matching data inside JSON field with UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492323/sqlalchemy-text-matching-data-inside-json-field-with-utf-8)