# SQLAlchemy Text Matching data inside JSON field with UTF-8

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I have table called Message which has column content of type JSON

My Model definition as requested is as following

```
class Message(db.Model):
    ...
    content = db.Column(JSON)
    ...
```

now I perform text matching for simple search with the following query

```
Message.query.filter(Message.content['summary'].cast(Unicode).match(term))
```

it works nicely, until *term* has a utf-8 character, like German umlauts or French accents.

what would be the solution here?

also keep in mind I'm using Python 3

Comment: Do you need the `cast` method? Decoding has to be performed *before* JSON is parsed, so when you access `content['summary']`, this should already have happened.

Comment: @lenz probably yes, otherwise if i remove it, i get this error sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: json @@ tsquery
LINE 3: WHERE bots_messages.content -> 'summary' @@ to_tsquery(bla bla bla

Comment: You should include the definition of `Message` in the question, as it is a crucial part of the issue at hand (json vs. jsonb).

Comment: @IljaEverilä Done ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in `cast(Unicode)` of a Postgresql `json` column. It simply CASTs the `json` to the text type underlying SQLAlchemy's `Unicode`, in case of Postgresql `VARCHAR`. In other words it produces a string representation of JSON instead of extracting the text content. If your input contained escaped unicode codepoints, they're output as is in this case. Given a simple `Test` model with a `json` column *data*:

```
In [7]: t = Test(data={'summary': 'Tämä on summary.'})

In [8]: session.add(t)

In [9]: session.commit()

In [11]: session.query(Test.data['summary'].cast(Unicode)).scalar()
Out[11]: '"T\\u00e4m\\u00e4 on summary."'
```

It should be evident why a match with unescaped unicode characters will fail. The correct way to extract the text content, unescaping escaped unicode, is to use [`astext`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON.Comparator.astext), which uses the [`->>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) in Postgresql:

```
In [13]: session.query(Test.data['summary'].astext).scalar()
Out[13]: 'Tämä on summary.'
```

Quoting the JSON functions and operators documentation:

> **Note:** Many of these functions and operators will convert Unicode escapes in JSON strings to the appropriate single character. This is a non-issue if the input is type jsonb, because the conversion was already done; but for json input, this may result in throwing an error, as noted in [Section 8.14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html).

So in your case:

```
Message.query.\
    filter(Message.content['summary'].astext.match(term))
```

Note that this only applies to `json` type, not `jsonb`, because the `json` type does not convert unicode escapes on input. `jsonb` on the other hand [converts all unicode escapes to equivalent ASCII or UTF-8 characters for storage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html). If our `Test` model contained a second column `data2 jsonb`, with the exact same input, then the result would be:

```
In [11]: session.query(Test.data['summary'].cast(Unicode),
    ...:               Test.data2['summary'].cast(Unicode)).first()
Out[11]: ('"T\\u00e4m\\u00e4 on summary."', '"Tämä on summary"')
```

Still, you should use `astext`, if you want text instead of a string representation of JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very informative and helpful answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. The original explanation was lacking and a bit wrong, so updated to mention the differences between `json` and `jsonb` and unicode escapes.