# Postgresql Json column not saving utf-8 character

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-json

Hi i'm trying to save data that i get from this [api](https://gateway.chotot.com/v1/public/ad-listing/64182145) into my Json column in my postgresql using sqlalchemy and python requests.

```
r = requests.get(api)

content = r.content

data = json.loads(content)

crawl_item = {}
crawl_item = session.query(CrawlItem).filter_by(site_id=3, href=list_id).first()
crawl_item.description = data['ad']['body']
crawl_item.meta_data = {}
crawl_item.meta_data["ward"] = data['ad_params']['ward']['value']

try:
      session.commit()
except:
      session.rollback()
      raise
finally:
      ret_id = crawl_item.id
      session.close()
```

my model:

```
class CrawlItem(Base):
    ...
    description = Column(Text)
    meta_data = Column(postgresql.JSON)
```

i want to get the value of ward :

```
"ward": {
      "id": "ward",
      "value": "Thị trấn Trạm Trôi",
      "label": " Phường, thị xã, thị trấn"
    }
```

I already encoding my postgresql to utf-8 so other fields that are not json column (`description = Column(Text)`) save utf-8 characters normally only my json column data are not decode:

[image]

```
{ 
   "ward":"Th\u1ecb tr\u1ea5n Tr\u1ea1m Tr\u00f4i"
}
```

description column:

[image: description]

meta_data column:

[image: meta_data]

i had tried using :

```
crawl_item.meta_data["ward"] = data['ad_params']['ward']['value'].decode('utf-8')
```

but the ward data don't get save

I have no idea what is wrong, hope someone can help me

EDIT:

i checked the data with psql and got these:

description column:

[image]

meta_data column:

[image]

It seems like only meta_data json column have trouble with the characters

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: What does the value look like if you select it using `psql`? I want to determine if it is stored in the database in escaped form or not.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä im using python 3.6

Comment: @Laurenz Albe  i had post the data in psql to the post edit part

Comment: Then my next question is: what is thr SQL statement that fills the column? You could set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` in PostgresSQL, then the statement and the input data are logged. Then you know if the escaping happens in Python or in the database.

Comment: it's hard for me to find postgresql.conf file since postgres is running on docker, is there anyway to use it with pgadmin or psql?

Comment: This feels a lot like [something I encountered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492323/sqlalchemy-text-matching-data-inside-json-field-with-utf-8). Could you please show us how you're fetching the data? Those `\uxxxx` are the correct escapes, but they're just not being unescaped: `json.loads(r'"Th\u1ecb tr\u1ea5n Tr\u1ea1m Tr\u00f4i"')` -> `'Thị trấn Trạm Trôi'`.

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe you're not using the proper text conversion(s) when fetching? The last SELECT statement you've shown is an example of that; you've selected the "raw" JSON produced by Python's `json` module, which contains escaped data.

Comment: yeah i think it has something to do with it showing in pgadmin or psql for me, because when i try to print it to html file using flask the texts from json column are just normal. I think it's problem with pgadmin showing non decoding text in its interface. I fetch the data from the api that i linked in the question and only use python requests.content to fetch it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqlalchemy serializes JSON field before save to db (see [url](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/json.py) and [url](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py)  and [url](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py)).

```
json_serializer = dialect._json_serializer or json.dumps
```

By default, the PostgreSQL' dialect uses `json.dumps` and `json.loads`.

---

When you work with Text column, the data is converted in the following flow:

```
str -> bytes in utf-8 encoding
```

When you work with JSON column for PostgreSQL dialect, the data is converted in the following flow:

```
dict -> str with escaped non-ascii symbols -> bytes in utf-8 encoding
```

> You can override the serializer in your engine configuration using `json_serializer` field:

```
json_serializer=partial(json.dumps, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score -2):

use "jsonb" data type for your json column or cast "meta_data" field to "jsonb" like this:

```
select meta_data::jsonb from your_table;
```